# Find a way to solve a complicated equation

Tags: equation-solving

I have to solve the following problem: find (if they exist) values of real variables x,u,v (with x,v>0) such that the following equality

$Maximum\{2 \frac a x, 2 \frac{u*b + v*c}{u^2 + v^2}, 
   2 \frac{(u - x)*(b - a) + v*c}{v^2 + (u - x)^2}\} = \frac{a}{x} + \frac{c}{v} + \frac{1}{v*x}\sqrt{
      a^2 (u^2 + v^2) - 2 a*x*(b*u + c*v) + (b^2 + c^2)*x^2}$

is verified for every value of the real values a, b, c.

Let me emphasize that I don't need to find values of x,u,v with respect to a,b,c, but fixed values of x,u,v which will verify the equality for any given a,b,c. This means that I need to find x, u, v which will verify all the infinite equations we will get for any different triple of values of a, b, c.

A naive way of doing it would be

```
Solve[Max[2 a/x, 2 (u*b + v*c)/(u^2 + v^2), 2 ((u - x)*(b - a) +v*c)/(v^2 + (u - x)^2)] == (a/x + c/v) + (1/(v*x)) Sqrt[a^2 (u^2 + v^2) - 2 a*x*(b*u + c*v) + (b^2 + c^2)*x^2], {x,u,v,a,b,c}]
```

And then hope that there will be a solution with no conditions on $a,b,c$.

The problem is that this Solve will requires a lot of computational effort and my cpu isn't able to solve it in a reasonable time.

So my first question is: **do you know some other way to solve this problem which will not be so heavy on the cpu?**

Comment: Based on the equation that you show, in your code blocks the `(1/v*x)` should read `1/(v*x)`. Also, you are missing the right brace for the `Sqrt[ ]` in both code blocks.

Comment: sorry I corrected it. My code was right: I did those error copying it here. So it still blocks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue it raises is not a Mathematica issue but a mathematics issue. That it is formulated in terms of Mathematica is not sufficient to make it an appropriate question for Mathematica.SE.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my questions. I asked for an alternative to a Solve command and for an implementation which consists of cycles and conditions. This is clearly a question about mathematica, not general mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Included in assumptions the constraints `x>0 && v>0`

```
Clear[eqn, f];

assume = Element[{x, u, v}, Reals] && x > 0 && v > 0;

eqn[a_, b_, c_, x_, u_, v_] := 
  Max[2 a/x, 2 (u*b + v*c)/(u^2 + v^2), 
    2 ((u - x)*(b - a) + v*c)/(v^2 + (u - x)^2)] == (a/x + 
      c/v) + (1/(v*x)) Sqrt[
      a^2 (u^2 + v^2) - 2 a*x*(b*u + c*v) + (b^2 + c^2)*x^2];

f[a_, b_, c_] := 
 Assuming[assume, Reduce[eqn[a, b, c, x, u, v], {x, u, v}] // Simplify]

sol1 = f[0, 0, 1]

(*  u == 0 || u == x  *)

Assuming[sol1 && assume, eqn[0, 0, 1, x, u, v] // Simplify]

(*  True  *)

sol2 = f[0, 1, 0]

(*  (2 u == x && 
   u + v == x) || (u == 
    v && ((2 u < x && u > 0) || u > x || 2 u > x)) || (u == v + x && u > x)  *)

Assuming[sol2 && assume, eqn[0, 1, 0, x, u, v] // Simplify]

(*  True  *)
```

**EDIT 2:**

For an `{x, u, v}` tuple to be valid for all `{a, b, c}` then arbitrary `{a, b, c}` tuples must generate constraints on `{x, u, v}` that reduce to a point or a region. However,

```
Reduce[f @@@ Tuples[{0, 1}, 3]]

(*  False  *)
```

indicates that there is no `{x, u, v}` tuple consistent with the equation for all `{a, b, c}`.

Comment: I don't understand your code: does it compute $x,u,v$ for $(a,b,c)=(0,0,1)$ and $(0,1,0)$?

Comment: @user389604 - yes it finds the constraints on `{x, u, v}` for a given `{a, b, c}`

Comment: thanks for the effort, but it's not what I need: I need to find $(x,u,v)$ which will verify the equation **for every (a,b,c)**.